# Browsing built-in sounds in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, audio

Is there an API (or just a hack) to populate a TableView with the names of the built-in sounds on an iOS device? For example, look at the alarm part of the Clock app: you can select a sound for the alarm from a TableView of sound names.

Answer (score 1):

For Jailbroken phones you can access filesystem and grab file list.

```
-(void)loadAudioFileList{
    audioFileList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds"];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLIsDirectoryKey];

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager
                                         enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL
                                         includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                         options:0
                                         errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                                             // Handle the error.
                                             // Return YES if the enumeration should continue after the error.
                                             return YES;
                                         }];

    for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {
        NSError *error;
        NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
        if (! [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error]) {
            // handle error
        }
        else if (! [isDirectory boolValue]) {
            [audioFileList addObject:url];
        }
    }
}
```

From the library's GitHub repo. [iOSSystemSoundsLibrary](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary)

- List of all system sounds used in iOS
- Run project on your iOS device to test all available system sounds
- iOS Simulator does NOT play system sounds

Comment: It works on my non-jailbroken iPad and iPhone. So I think your answer is more general, perhaps things have changed.

Comment: @AndrewDuncan in theory yes but if you submit your app to app store it will be rejected.